# NServiceBus 6.4.3 configured to MSMQ fails on startup

Tags: nservicebus, msmq

I am experimenting with using NServiceBus with MSMQ as transport. A very simple example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("myappqueue");
    endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();

    var endpointInstance = Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).Result;
    Console.ReadKey();
    endpointInstance.Stop();
}
```

I have added the Windows feature Message Queue in and created a private queue called **myappqueue**.

When I run the application and get to the line with **Endpoint.Start**, I get this error:

*Faults forwarding requires an error queue to be specified using 'EndpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo()'*

What am I missing? This configuration is not mentioned in the samples on Particular's documentation site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an endpoint is created and operational, messages can fail processing. In that case, NServiceBus needs to forward failed messages to the designated error queue which you need to specify. `EndpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo()` is the API to use to configure what error queue to use.

You mind find [this documentaiton](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/configure-error-handling) helpful when configuring your endpoint for error handling. And since you're new to NServiceBus, [tutorials](https://docs.particular.net/tutorials/intro-to-nservicebus/) can be helpful as well.

Comment: The thing is, the tutorials focus totally on the LearningTransport, which kind of defeat the purpose. Anyway, I was obviously totally blind when reading the MSMQ page, since now I just saw - in a highlighted box in the beginning - the sentence: *When using MSMQ as the transport, the error queue configuration must also be specified.* Silly me, thank you for pointing it out. :-)

Comment: @CarstenGehling the comment you've made is important (_"the tutorials focus totally on the LearningTransport, which kind of defeat the purpose."_). Could you provide it as feedback to the tutorial? There's a [button](https://docs.particular.net/tutorials/intro-to-nservicebus/) to provide feedback, in the [right top corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4pdf.png). Thank you.